# How to get place_id based on telephone number

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I would like to get the place_id based on the telephone. So far, I was able to get the place_id with the address but I wonder if I could get the same info but with the telephone.

```
import googlemaps 
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='API')


place_name = '3054 28th St, Boulder, CO 80304, Estados Unidos'
places_result = gmaps.places(place_name)
place_id = places_result['results'][0]['place_id']
```

Output

`print(place['result']['place_id'])`

```
ChIJFZ3Tw3vua4cRsd2Sia4hkLY
```

I want to get the same output but in the place_name I would like to get the telephone number and get the same place_id

```
place_result

    {'html_attributions': [],
 'results': [{'formatted_address': '3054 28th St, Boulder, CO 80301, USA',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.0301734, 'lng': -105.2578728},
    'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.03152422989272,
      'lng': -105.2566366201073},
     'southwest': {'lat': 40.02882457010728, 'lng': -105.2593362798927}}},
   'icon': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/geocode-71.png',
   'icon_background_color': '#7B9EB0',
   'icon_mask_base_uri': 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/generic_pinlet',
   'name': '3054 28th St',
   'place_id': 'ChIJs6f_tXvua4cRpmNh_22rOpc',
   'plus_code': {'compound_code': '2PJR+3V Boulder, Colorado, USA',
    'global_code': '85GP2PJR+3V'},
   'reference': 'ChIJs6f_tXvua4cRpmNh_22rOpc',
   'types': ['street_address']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding your question or there isn't enough code here. We need to know what the value of places_result is in order to parse it.

Comment: In the documentation: [Find Place from Phone Number](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_phone_number)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the Place IDs based on phone numbers, you can use [Places Find Place API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place).

Here’s an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json
  ?input=%2B16502530000
  &inputtype=phonenumber
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The `input` should be the phone numbers that are in international format (prefixed by a plus sign ("+"), followed by the country code, then the phone number itself. Next, use `phonenumber` as the `inputtype`. More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#required-parameters).

If you want to get the phone number in the result, you can use [Places Details API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details). You just need the Place ID of the place you want to search, and add `formatted_phone_number` or the `international_phone_number`. Here’s an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
  ?fields=name%2Cformatted_phone_number%2Cinternational_phone_number
  &place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```